# How can i return *array of arrays of objects* from MySQL to Node js server in a query using mysql npm?

Tags: mysql, arrays, arraylist

I'm using phpMyAdmin Database (mariaDB). I have two tables:

Person(**Name**, Address, Birthday)  
and  
Friends(**friendName**, personName, Birthday). 
My query: `SELECT * FROM person, friends WHERE person.Name=friends.personName ;` 
I want the server gets all friend of any person on the database **as an array of objects**.

I want my output from the query will be:

```
[ 
[ { personName1, friendName1, Address1, Birthday1 },
{ personName1, friendName2, Address2, Birthday2 } , 
{ personName1, friendName3, Address3, Birthday3 } ], 
[ { personName2, friendName4, Address4, Birthday4 },
{ personName2, friendName5, Address5, Birthday5 }]
]
```

Like array of arrays of objects. 
Each organ in an array (which is also an array) contains objects.
The objects are divided within the arrays according to the personName value.

Instead of:

```
[ 
{personName1, friendName1, Address1, Birthday1}, 
{personName2, friendName5, Address5, Birthday5},
{personName1, friendName2, Address2, Birthday2}, 
{personName2, friendName4, Address4, Birthday4}, 
{personName1, friendName3, Address3, Birthday3} 
]
```

I know i can do it from the server in javascript but i want call the database one time and the query's output as a list or an array of arrays. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can group your result (array of arrays) into an array of objects using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const initialResult = fakeResult();
const grouped = initialResult
  .reduce((acc, [name, friend, address, birthday]) => [...acc, {
    [name]: {
      friend,
      address,
      birthday
    }
  }], []);

document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = JSON.stringify(grouped, null, 2);

function fakeResult() {
  return `personName1,friendName1,Address1,Birthday1
      personName1,friendName2,Address2,Birthday2
      personName2,friendName3,Address3,Birthday3
      personName2,friendName4,Address4,Birthday4`
    .split(`\n`)
    .map(l => l.trim().split(`,`));
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

If it's only SQL you're after, [`group_concat`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/) may be an idea.

```
SELECT 
  p.Name 
  , group_concat(
     f.personName, ', ', 
     f.Address, ', ', 
     f.Birthday) as friends
 FROM person p , friends f
 WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND p.Name = f.personName;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick answer. notice that i edited my question.  Also, i wanted to find a way to do it with an sql query and not using javascript. Thanks again :)

Comment: In that case, don't use the tag `javascript`. An `Array` of `Arrays` as a query will imho not be possible using SQL, but you can ofcourse use something like `order by person.name`.

Comment: Using order by person.name cause a missing output, Thanks anyway!